# hibernate single session active transaction

Tags: hibernate, session, transactions

My Hibernate config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
         <property     name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:XE</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.default_schema">gg</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
<property name="show_sql">false</property>
<property name="format_sql">true</property>
<property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>

    <mapping class="com.greengrass.house.Obj"></mapping>
    <mapping class="com.greengrass.house.ObjxProp"></mapping>
    <mapping class="com.greengrass.house.Property"></mapping>
    <mapping class="com.greengrass.house.EvQue"></mapping>
    <mapping class="com.greengrass.house.EvxObj"></mapping>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Part of my main procedure:

```
Session sess = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
List<Obj> lobj = sess.createQuery(
    "from Obj").list();
sess.beginTransaction();
Obj o2=lobj.get(1);
o2.crEvent("test", 3600, 1); //calling method
sess.getTransaction().commit();
```

One method of my persisting object:

```
@Transient
public void crEvent(String speech, int timeout, int maxCnt) { 
    Session s = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    if (!s.getTransaction().isActive()) {
        System.out.println("No transaction!!!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Exist transaction!!!");
    }
    Query query = s.createSQLQuery(
            "CALL p_event.cr_event(:p_speech, :p_tm, :p_max_cnt)")
            .setParameter("p_speech", speech)
            .setParameter("p_tm", timeout)
            .setParameter("p_max_cnt", maxCnt);
    int exRows = query.executeUpdate();      
}
```

So i get this result:

```
No transaction!!! <--Message from the my method

Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: createSQLQuery is not valid without active transaction
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:348)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.createSQLQuery(Unknown Source)
    at com.greengrass.house.Obj.crEvent(Obj.java:273)
    at com.greengrass.evhandler.GreenEvHandler.main(GreenEvHandler.java:36)
```

So i don't understand why is 
HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
in method crEvent, can't continue active transaction from main procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want to deal with a contextual session in Hibernate (3.0.1+) you should use `getCurrentSession()`. You do not need to (nor should you) call `openSession()` first. From the [manual (v4.3, §3.9.3)](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html#configuration-j2ee-currentsession):

> Using the "jta" session context, if there is no Hibernate `Session` associated with the current JTA transaction, one will be started and associated with that JTA transaction the first time you call `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`.

In contrast `openSession` always opens a new session, which you should then close (e.g. with [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)) before it goes out of scope. The session opened by `openSession` is not a hibernate contextual session.

You can (usually) see if two session instances are the same by comparing `hashCodes`:

```
Session s1 = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
Session s2 = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
Session s3 = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
System.out.println("getCurrent is  " + s1.hashCode());
System.out.println("openSession is " + s2.hashCode());
System.out.println("getCurrent is  " + s3.hashCode());
s2.close();
```

outputs:

```
getCurrent is  392918519
openSession is 1499840045
getCurrent is  392918519
```

Comment: Thank you very much, so i need to re-read documentation, thanx in advise!